# Why are Model properties null when receiving data from datatable plugin?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am using the [datatable.net](https://datatables.net/) Jquery plugin. I am just starting to work with it, so I am testing its different features.
I am using:

- DataTables-1.10.12
- .NET Framework 4.5.1

I am trying to customize the model that is sent to the server when using server side processing but it is null when it is received in the server.
What am I doing wrong?

**Model**

```
public class DataTableModel
{
    public SearchModel[] SearchData { get; set; }        
}

public class SearchModel
{
    public string Column { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool Regex { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
}
```

**DataTable ajax configuration:**

```
"ajax": {
    "url": dataUrl,
    "data": function (d) {
        var data = {

        }
        var searchColumns = [];                    
        $(d.columns).each(function (index) {
            if ($(this)[0].search.value !== "") {
                var searchData = {
                    Column: $(this)[0].data,
                    Value: $(this)[0].search.value,
                    Regex: $(this)[0].search.regex,
                    Index: index
                };
                searchColumns.push(searchData);                            
            }
        });;
        var dataTableModel = {
            SearchData: searchColumns
        };
        data.dataTableModel = dataTableModel;
        return data;
    }
},
```

**Ajax Handler on the Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetItems(DataTableModel dataTableModel, string _)
{
```

`dataTableModel` has its properties in null, but the `_` has its value set. Is my understanding that the `_` is a parameter sent by the `datatable` to make the cache work, I am not sure what is the right way to deal with it (any advise will be appreciated)

The `QueryString` has:

- Results View:

> ```
>   [0] "dataTableModel[SearchData][0][Column]" object {string}
>   [1] "dataTableModel[SearchData][0][Value]"  object {string}
>   [2] "dataTableModel[SearchData][0][Regex]"  object {string}
>   [3] "dataTableModel[SearchData][0][Index]"  object {string}
>   [4] "dataTableModel[SearchData][1][Column]" object {string}
>   [5] "dataTableModel[SearchData][1][Value]"  object {string}
>   [6] "dataTableModel[SearchData][1][Regex]"  object {string}
>   [7] "dataTableModel[SearchData][1][Index]"  object {string}
>   [8] "_" object {string}
> ```

Why is the `SearchData` property null?

Comment: there is already a nuget package out written by someone which provides model binding for datatable

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I don´t quite follow what you mean?

Comment: can you please tell what you are trying to do ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I want to modify the data that the datatable.net plugin sends to the server, I want it to make it match a model I define.

Comment: i think you would need to write your custom model binder for that